# Getting a single field from a List inside of another List in C# LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate

I have a List of schools, each of which contains a list of courses, where each course contains a single teacher. I want to get a list of all teachers across the different schools and different courses.

```
public School()
{
   public List<Course> Courses; 
}

public Course()
{
   public Teacher Teacher;
}

var schools = new List<School>();

var allTeachers = schools.select(s => s.Courses.select(t => t.Teacher)).ToList();
```

I tired that but it gave me an error (it complied though): Processing server-side result operator after doing client-side ones. We've got the ordering wrong...

Comment: If this comes from a Database you should have a teachers table, why complicate this recursing relations instead of selecting all the items from the table directly?

Comment: You're right, it does have a Teachers table. But there's some criteria that I'm filtering with the List of Schools.

Comment: Ok, then reverse the logic, an school will have a lot of courses and a course a lot of teachers, but a teacher will have a course and a course will have an school, so it's a lot easier to select from teacher and check teacher.course and teacher.course.school.

Comment: Although I already have an answer below... I'm not sure I'm quite following. So you wanted me to iterate through the total list of Teachers and check for a certain condition? What if I had like 3000+ teachers but only like 250-300 schools? That wouldn't make any sense to loop through the entire list of teachers. If I have a subset of schools say 20-50, wouldn't it be better to loop through that subset of lists and select the teachers?

Comment: Well, in your code there's no test nor you said nothing about how many registers will be there, so I can't know these things. But, anyway, it should be translated to the DB as a left join and the query analizer will optimize it for you, it should not make a difference, but anyway, the best way to see if there is a difference is to try it.

Answer (score 2):

```
schools.SelectMany(s => s.Courses).SelectMany(c => c.Teacher)
```

Or if you wanted to structure it with Schools>Teachers>Courses...

```
schools.SelectMany(s => s.Teachers)
```

You might also add a .Distinct() onto the end, in case the same teacher can have multiple courses/schools.

Comment: This worked. Thank you! I was just wondering what the SelectMany method did haha... and now I know.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this LINQ query to pull all `Teacher` objects:

```
        var allTeachers = from school in schools
                          from course in school.Courses
                          select course.Teacher;
```